# Error: Do not override object.Finalize. Instead, provide a destructor

Tags: c#, idisposable, destructor, finalizer

Getting the above error in following code. How to rectify it. Thanks.
Please look for

```
protected override void Finalize() {     Dispose(false); }
```

in the below code.

```
using Microsoft.Win32; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

public class Kiosk : IDisposable 
{ 

    #region "IDisposable" 

    // Implementing IDisposable since it might be possible for 
    // someone to forget to cause the unhook to occur. I didn't really 
    // see any problems with this in testing, but since the SDK says 
    // you should do it, then here's a way to make sure it will happen. 

    public void Dispose() 
    { 
        Dispose(true); 
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 
    } 

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) 
    { 
        if (disposing) { 
        } 
        // Free other state (managed objects). 
        if (m_hookHandle != 0) { 
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hookHandle); 
            m_hookHandle = 0; 
        } 
        if (m_taskManagerValue > -1) { 
            EnableTaskManager(); 
        } 
    } 

    protected override void Finalize() 
    { 
        Dispose(false); 
    } 

    #endregion 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do what it says. Instead of:

```
protected override void Finalize() 
{ 
    Dispose(false); 
}
```

Have:

```
~Kiosk () 
{ 
    Dispose(false); 
}
```

Answer (score 13):

`Finalize()` is a special method that you can't override in code. Use the destructor syntax instead:

```
~Kiosk() 
{ 
    Dispose(false); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning a bit about why, rather than just dumping code.

Comment: Well, he doesn't actually mention why. The exception itself states the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the following syntax compiles to exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

```
~Kiosk()
{
    Dispose(false);
}
```